# Cross DB Ecto config failing

Tags: elixir, ecto, elixir-mix

In `config/dev.exs`:

```
config :drupex, Drupex.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  -- username, password, database, hostname, pool_size omitted --

config :drupex, Drupex.DrupalRepo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Mysql,
  -- username, password, database, hostname omitted --
```

In `mix.exs` under `defp deps do` I added `{:mariaex, "~> 0.8.2"},` just after `{:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}`. Finally in `lib/drupex/repo.ex` I added

```
defmodule Drupex.DrupalRepo do
  use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :drupex
end
```

I ran `mix deps.get` , `mix deps.compile` now running `mix` I get

```
** (ArgumentError) adapter Ecto.Adapters.Mysql was not compiled, ensure it is correct and it is included as a project dependency
```

Comment: The close argument is invalid, it's not a typo but whether Elixir is case sensitive or insensitive, made harder by the adapter name Postgres.

Comment: Just for future reference, any "bare word" starting with an upper case letter or a colon are atoms (`Ecto.Adapters.MySql` and `:ok` are both atoms). Atoms in Elixir and Erlang are case sensitive. [The getting started guide](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/basic-types.html#atoms) gives a decent overview of what atoms are.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the adapter is called `MySQL` and it is case sensitive. Changing to `adapter: Ecto.Adapters.MySQL,` solved the problem.