# How to debug failing Ecto query?

Tags: elixir, ecto, elixir-iex

After finally setting up my repo [Cross DB Ecto config failing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49825883/308851) trying to run a query gives me this:

```
iex(1)> import Ecto.Query
Ecto.Query
iex(2)> Drupex.DrupalRepo.query(from "watchdog", select: [:wid]);
** (Protocol.UndefinedError) protocol String.Chars not implemented for #Ecto.Query<from w in "watchdog", select: [:wid]>. This protocol is implemented for: Atom, BitString, Date, DateTime, Decimal, Ecto.Date, Ecto.DateTime, Ecto.Time, Float, Integer, List, Mariaex.Query, NaiveDateTime, Postgrex.Copy, Postgrex.Query, Postgrex.Stream, Time, URI, Version, Version.Requirement
    (elixir) lib/string/chars.ex:3: String.Chars.impl_for!/1
    (elixir) lib/string/chars.ex:22: String.Chars.to_string/1
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:613: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.log/4
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:1186: DBConnection.log/6
    (db_connection) lib/db_connection.ex:643: DBConnection.execute/4
    (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:256: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.sql_call/6
```

I tried to Google on how to get the error handler to show arguments but found nothing so I do not know what the error is -- is my query invalid, does it have a problem connecting to the MySQL server etc.

Edit: I figured it out, it's `Drupex.DrupalRepo.all`. I figured it out by adding `IO.inspect` calls into `lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex` but this is a very dirty hack, surely there are better ways.

Comment: Using https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Adapters.SQL.html#to_sql/3 I was able to inspect the generated query. It helped me debug before. Maybe it could be of some use to you.

Comment: Why don't you try Repo?

Comment: The question is about debugging practices like how to expand the stack trace to include arguments, to show the real error and so on.